# What should look like to be my requirements.txt file?

Tags: python-3.x, github, heroku, requirements

I want to deploy a python script on Heroku cloud via GitHub and I am using these python libraries, Module, API

```
from amazon_paapi import AmazonApi
import base64
import requests
import random
import time
```

What should look like to be my requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As base64, random and time are default libraries, your requirements.txt should look like:

```
python-amazon-paapi
requests
```

You can have a requirements.txt with or without version specifiers. For example:

```
[package name] == 0.6.1             # Version Matching. Must be version 0.6.1
[package name] >= 4.1.1             # Minimum version 4.1.1
[package name] != 3.5               # Version Exclusion. Anything except version 3.5
[package name]                      # no specified version
[package name]                      # no specified version
```